# Powershell / C# keyhook script NullReferenceException externally

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, keylogger, keyhook

I'm trying to use a powershell script (using C#) to listen to key strokes. It works a short time before erroring out. What's interesting is after I added some console writes, it seems the error is occurring external to my code.

Here's the powreshell script:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace KeyLogger {
        public static class Program {
            private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
            private static IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;

            public static void Begin() {
                hookId = SetHook();
                Application.Run();
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
            }

            private static IntPtr SetHook() {
                IntPtr moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName);
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, moduleHandle, 0);
            }

            private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
                Console.WriteLine('0');
                if (nCode == 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine('1');
                    Console.WriteLine(Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam) + " " + wParam + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine('2');
                IntPtr x = CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
                Console.WriteLine('3');
                return x;
            }

            private delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        }
    }
"@ -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms

[KeyLogger.Program]::Begin();
```

The error is:

> An error has occurred that was not properly handled. Additional information is shown below. The Windows PowerShell process will exit.
>       Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Notice the `Console.WriteLine` 's in the `HookCallback` method. But the last debug line printed is `3`, indicating the error occurs outside of `HookCallback`. What's even more interesting, if I have multiple instances of the script running, they don't all error simultaneously; one may crash, but the remaining continue on for a bit more.

I'm not too familiar with powershell or C#, so am wondering how to get more debug information? I would expect a line number or file or library name where the error occurred, but am not sure how to get that information.

Disclaimer, I took the script from here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/ (modified slightly).

Edit: I've accepted Stuartd's answer as it was very helpful, but as I said in the comments, it required small modifications to work. **For ease to future readers, here are the modifications that worked:**

```
 private static HookProc callback;
 ...

 private static IntPtr SetHook() {
     callback = HookCallback;
     IntPtr moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName);
     return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, callback, moduleHandle, 0);
 }
 ...
```

I've done more searching and reading up on C#, and it seems the cause was that `SetWindowsHookEx` does not manage / keep alive it's hookProc delegate parameter, and passing a static method directly creates a local (local to the method) delegate that is ready for deletion once the `SetHook` method returns.

Comment: If it matters, `x` seems to be pointing to address 0; `Console.WriteLine("3 [" + x + "]");` writes `3 [0]`.

Comment: My guess, having used this same code in an app, is that the delegate is being disposed. Add `GC.KeepAlive(HookProc);` after you call `SetWindowsHookEx` - as I had to do [here](https://github.com/stuartd/keymapper/blob/master/keymapper/Classes/KeySniffer.cs#L80)

Comment: Have you considered building this in visual studio and debugging it?

Comment: @stuartd, `GC.KeepAlive(HookProc);` gives me the compilation error `'KeyLogger.Program.HookProx' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`. But I think my problem may be related to GC, because it seems more quick to occur when I have something big running.

Comment: So it does. Hmm.. One sec-

Comment: Also interesting, I tried adding some `Console.WriteLine`s  in the `Begin` function. And depending on how many I added or where I added them, the script would work as currently, stop midway in the `Begin` function and pause all running instances, or give a runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do it: create a field that refers to `HookProc`, and tell GC to keep it alive:

```cs
public static class Program
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private static IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static HookProc proc;

    public static void Begin()
    {
        proc = HookCallback;
        hookId = SetHook();
        GC.KeepAlive(proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
    }

     … etc
```

Comment: Looking at this, if the proc is referenced in a field I don't think it would be disposed. But when I had to do this it was more than a decade ago, and at the time it "worked" so I didn't dig in any further.

Comment: I don't want to jump the gun too soon, but it *seems* 1) moving the `proc` assignment before calling `SetHook`, and then 2) passing `proc` instead of `HookCallback` as the 2nd param of `SetWindowsHookEx` in `SetHook` may have resolved the issue. You're right that `GC.KeepAlive` seems to be unnecessary.